# localStorage.getItem returns old data in IE 9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, local-storage

The following example needs to be running in IE 9 and in at least two different tabs.

```
 <input type="text" name="data" value="" placeholder="change me" id="data" />
 <p id="fromEvent">Waiting for data via <code>storage</code> event...</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("storage", function (e) {
  if (e.key == 'storage-event-test') {
      var newValue = localStorage.getItem('storage-event-test'); // returns old value
  //  var newValue = e.newValue; // returns new value
      $('#fromEvent').html(newValue);
    }
  }, false);

  $('#data').live('keyup', function () {
     var changedValue = this.value;
      $('#fromEvent').html(changedValue);
       localStorage.setItem('storage-event-test', changedValue);
    });
</script>
```

If it try to get the data with `var newValue = localstorage.getItem('storage-event-test');` and in **Tab 1** enters `test` then it shows correctly `test`  in my `<p id="fromEvent">` but in my **Tab 2** 
it only writes `tes`

Now if I change the code to use `var newValue = e.newValue;` both Tab 1 & Tab 2 writes `test` in `<p id="fromEvent">`

Can someone explain to me, why they return different results?
I have also testet this code in Google Chrome and Firefox, and they don't have this problem.

Just for the record, this was running on a win 7 Ultimate 64 SP1 with IIS Express and using jquery-1.5.1. and the bug is in both the 32 and 64 bit version of IE9

**Edit**
Tested with normal IIS 7.5 same result

**Edit 2**
Would be nice if someone could confirm that this is happening to them to?

Comment: This is still an issue in Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As to why they return different results the answer is pretty obvious. The `storage` event on IE is fired *before* the value changes, and *after* on other browsers. You can confirm this by  [adding a slight delay](http://jsbin.com/uqufup/5/edit) to your code:

```
if (e.key == 'storage-event-test') {
    // e.newValue ->  new value
    // localStorage.getItem('storage-event-test') ->  old value in IE
    setTimeout(function(){
        var newValue = localStorage.getItem('storage-event-test'); // new value
         $('#fromEvent').html(newValue);
    }, 1); // delay
}
```

I don't know why it is implemented this way though, but I'm guessing the **[specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#localStorageEvent)** is too vague and **doesn't say when** the event should be fired.

> The *storage* event is fired when a storage area changes, as described in the previous two sections (for session storage, for local storage).
>
> When this happens, the user agent must queue a task to fire an event with the name storage, which does not bubble and is not cancelable, and which uses the *StorageEvent* interface, at each *Window* object whose *Document* object has a *Storage* object that is affected.

Comment: There's `onstoragecommit` event in IE. One could use `document.onstoragecommit !== undefined` for feature-detection and subscribe for that event.

Comment: @kirilloid Though onstoragecommit will be raised once the value has changed, it will only be raised on the one browser tab that actually changed the storage and not on the other tabs.

Comment: @AndyGeek The point is to check *existence* of this event (handler), not to subscribe to it.