# Internet Explorer Showing Old Values For Local Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, local-storage

I'm handling the `storage` event to synchronize changes across browser windows. I've noticed that Internet Explorer seems to keep the old values.

**Example HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li data-aid="1" data-pid="1">1/1</li>
    <li data-aid="1" data-pid="2">1/2</li>
    <li data-aid="2" data-pid="3">2/3</li>
    <li data-aid="2" data-pid="4">2/4</li>
</ul>
```

**Example JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('li');
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        localStorage.setItem('li', JSON.stringify({
            aid : $this.data('aid'),
            pid : $this.data('pid')
        }));
    });
    $(window).on('storage', function(e) {
        // ignore Internet Explorer firing event in own window
        // ignore changes not to the 'li' key
        if (!document.hasFocus() && ('li' === e.originalEvent.key)) {
            $('body').append('<p>' + localStorage.getItem('li') + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

If I have two windows open, and click each list item, the second window has the following output:

```
<p>null</p>
<p>{"aid":1,"pid":1}</p>
<p>{"aid":1,"pid":2}</p>
<p>{"aid":2,"pid":3}</p>
```

In Chrome, Firefox, and Safari I get the output I expect:

```
<p>{"aid":1,"pid":1}</p>
<p>{"aid":1,"pid":2}</p>
<p>{"aid":2,"pid":3}</p>
<p>{"aid":2,"pid":4}</p>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While digging through a [tutorial](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html#storage-event), I saw that the `storage` event has a `newValue` property. Changing my listener to use that, instead of reading from `localStorage`, fixes the issue in Internet Explorer. It works in all the other browsers too!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('li');
    $('li').on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        localStorage.setItem('li', JSON.stringify({
            aid : $this.data('aid'),
            pid : $this.data('pid')
        }));
    });
    $(window).on('storage', function(e) {
        // ignore Internet Explorer firing event in own window
        // ignore changes not to the 'li' key
        if (!document.hasFocus() && ('li' === e.originalEvent.key)) {
            // use the event's newValue property instead of reading from storage
            // fixes issue with IE returning old value
            $('body').append('<p>' + e.originalEvent.newValue + '</p>');
        }
    });
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

I found two SO posts have solutions that fix the problem by introducing a slight delay. I feel that my solution is a bit more elegant.

- [Why does Internet Explorer sometimes trigger a local storage event before the data's ready?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18265394/244826)
- [localStorage.getItem returns old data in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9292576/244826)