# JWT Authentication is not properly removing token

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, token, jwt

I am doing a Laravel 5 project and using JWT to authenticate users. Everything seemed to be working fine but then as I got deeper into the project I noticed that either the logout or the login don't seem to be working properly. What will happen is when I log in, it acts as if there is an invalid token error until the page is refreshed. Then it works fine. Upon logging out, and logging back in as a different user it act's as if user 1 is still logged in, until refreshing the page. Then it show's user 2 as logged in.

Here is the function for login:

```
function login(email, password, onSuccess, onError){

    $http.post('/api/auth/login', 
    {
        email: email,
        password: password
    }).
    then(function(response) {
        localStorageService.remove('token');
        localStorageService.set('token', response.data.token);
        onSuccess(response);

    }, function(response) {

        onError(response);

    });

}
```

and for logout:

```
function logout(){
    localStorageService.remove('token');
}
```

another example, here I use JWT to check the current user and then return their profile information from the database:

```
public function index()
{
    $currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    $profile = DB::select('SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE profiles.profileID = :id', ['id' => $currentUser["id"]]);

    return $profile;
}
```

Any idea why the tokens are not being removed/given properly?

Comment: Are you setting your JWT in the Authorization header for each request?

Comment: Are you using and old version of Internet explorer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292576/localstorage-getitem-returns-old-data-in-ie-9 in some versions the change event on localStorage is sent before change is available

Comment: @ncd275 no I don't think so because I'm not too familiar with that. Would that be my issue?

Comment: @pedrofb mozilla and chrome!

Comment: @Kenta When you are making other requests to your API how are you passing back the JWT?

Comment: @ncd275 oh like this: wim.app/api/relationship/viewRequests?token=eyasdfjkl

Comment: show me function that calls the API like you did above with login but show me a different one. I want to see how you are adding on your token to the api call

Comment: @ncd275 sorry again im really new to this, but i edited the question above to include what I think you're asking for

Comment: @Kenta do you have your files on Github? or somewhere so i can look at all of them. What i am trying to see is after you assign your JWT to the user, i want to see how you are attaching it to each request after that from the front to the back. Show me another function from the front end from your angular where you use a $http.post or $http.get

Comment: @ncd275 OH I think I know what you're talking about. Here is a git repo for it: [link](https://github.com/xxkenta/derpity) You should be able to find what you're asking for perhaps in public/js/services.js or controllers.js

thank you a lot for taking the time to help me out