# How can I get my userscript to permenantly remember input values?

Tags: javascript, userscripts

I've made a simple userscript in Violentmonkey (Firefox) that toggles an element style whenever a box is checked (I use it for osticket).

```
...
// sync localStorage & checked
var checked = localStorage.getItem('checked');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  tag.classList.toggle("tag-ext");
  if (checked == 0) {
    checked++;
  } else {
    checked--;
  }
  localStorage.setItem('checked', checked)
  // output current checked value
  console.log(checked);
});
```

The value of **checked** tracks the position of the tag: *on* or *off*. The issue is that the tag position doesn't always correspond to the checked value in local storage, which always either 0 or 1. How can I fix this script to make the association between the tag and the checked value more reliable?

Comment: i have noticed when using cookies at least, that there is sometimes a lag - you may be console logging it before the localStorage has updated so you are seeing the old value ...are you seeing it update in your dev tools reliably?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [localStorage.getItem returns old data in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292576/localstorage-getitem-returns-old-data-in-ie-9)

Comment: @HolyMoly - I think you're both right. I will modify the code to get more granular updates on the value.